# HTML pre-inserting quotes in my code?

Tags: html

When I my code is opened in a browser my code pre-includes quotation marks in my image tags, thereby making all images files incapable of being found. Even in the alt text, if I include quotes it actually prints the quotes out.

Here's my code:

```
<img alt=“Batman” src=“batman.png” />
```

Upon clicking Inspect Element, the code looks like this:

```
<img alt="“Batman”" src="“batman.png”">
```

The code will only work when the quotations are left out like this:

```
<img alt=Batman src=batman.png />
```

I have tested this issue in every browser, this is really bizarre, PLEASE HELP ME!

Comment: It looks like you might be using a different character for quotation marks.  What editor are you using?  HTML attributes such as alt and src require strings, using standard single or double quotes.

Answer (score 4):

You are using the wrong kind of quotation mark.

Use `"` not `“`. This will work:

```
<img alt="Batman" src="batman.png" />
```

What happens when you use the wrong ones is, the browser interprets them *as part of the URL* and appends the correct quotation marks around it. That, of course, won't work.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! TextEdit was using a funny quotation mark when I upgraded to Mavericks for whatever reason. I'm now using Sublime Text for my code and the results are exactly how I want them. Thank you for your help again.